# Order collection by first key value in serialized attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have a Comment model with a serialized attribute:

```
  serialize :edit, Hash
```

Each edit for the comment is timestamped by inserting a key/value pair:

```
self.edit[DateTime.current] = edit_content
```

How would I order a collection of comments, all sorted by the first submitted timestamp for each comment?

Comment: I believe the `active-model-serializers` tag is not justified here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Your `edit` column stores the data as a serialized string, so basically its contents look like this:

```
[3] pry(main)> a = {}
=> {}
[4] pry(main)> a[DateTime.current] = 'bla'
=> "bla"
[5] pry(main)> a[DateTime.current] = 'bla bla'
=> "bla bla"
[9] pry(main)> a.to_yaml
=> "---\n!ruby/object:DateTime 2015-10-04 21:38:02.611020000 Z: bla\n!ruby/object:DateTime 2015-10-04 21:38:06.594140000 Z: bla bla\n"
[10] pry(main)> puts a.to_yaml
---
!ruby/object:DateTime 2015-10-04 21:38:02.611020000 Z: bla
!ruby/object:DateTime 2015-10-04 21:38:06.594140000 Z: bla bla
=> nil
```

In order to make it sortable by database, you need either extract your edits to another entity (such as `Revision` and create `revisions` table), or, for example, make a `comments.first_edit_date` column and sort by it as you usually do.

P.S. You can, of course, load **all** your `comments` table to memory and then order it there, but it will have huge performance implications:

```
# DON'T DO THIS IN PRODUCTION
Comment.all.sort_by { |comment| comment.edit.keys.first }
```

Comment: But I can perfectly sort each object's edit attribute by it's timestamp? `edit.keys.sort.first`

Comment: You're just sorting timestamps here of one comment, that's ok.

Comment: Would `post.comments.sort_by { |comment| comment.edit.keys.first }` be ok in production? That would only iterate a maximum of 30 comments per post.

Comment: If you have 1 post on the page, then yes. But it's still bad design, and if it doesn't bite you today, it will tomorrow. I'd still recommend to extract a separate model.